# Formatting xml texts using tokens in String

Tags: java, android, xml, format

I'm trying to get some code which will for example change

"^^text^^"

Into something like this

"**text**"

So I need it to remove the ^^ tokens and add a Spannable Text on the "text" string making it bold.
Right now I have this code.

```
public void format()
{
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test);

    CharSequence text = null;

    if(textView != null)
    {
         text = textView.getText();
    }

    String token = "^^";

    if(text != null)
    {
        int length = text.length();
        int start = text.toString().indexOf(token) + length;
        int end = text.toString().indexOf(token, start);

        if (start > -1 && end > -1)
        {
            SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);

            ssb.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(0x000000), start, end, 0);
            ssb.delete(end, end + length);
            ssb.delete(start - length, start);

            text = ssb;
            System.out.println("format");
        }

        System.out.println("works");
    }

    textView.setText(text);
    System.out.println("running");
}
```

This code gets called in the onCreate which looks like this.

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    format();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tutorial_basic_file_test);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    {
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

This is the XML layout file I'm using.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="@string/empty" />

<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/test"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/test_text"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And finally the string I'm using in a resource file.

```
<string name="test_text">Test string ^^ for ^^ formatter code</string>
```

What am I doing wrong or how should I do this?

Comment: What error are you getting? One mistake I notice: You are calling `format()` which invokes `findViewById()` before you have set the content view via `setContentView()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems here:

1. In `onCreate` you call `format()` before setting the content layout. *First set layout, then operate on views* that are declared inside it, i.e.:

   ```
   // First!
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_tutorial_basic_file_test);
   // Second!
   format();
   ```
2. In format you mistakenly define `length` as length of the `text`. Looking at the code, it should definitely be length of `token`:

   ```
   // token length, not text length!
   int length = token.length();
   ```
3. Remember that providing color values as `int` values often means you should explicitly set alpha value. If you don't the alpha is set to `0` (i.e. transparent). You use `0x000000` (transparent black) in `ForegroundColorSpan`, but it's more common to set `0xff000000` (opaque black). If that's the case, change the line to:

   ```
   ssb.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(0xff000000), start, end, 0);
   ```
4. You should set the `TextView` content to the `SpannableStringBuilder` *directly*. This is because `TextView` automatically sees that it is a `Spannable` and applies your desired formatting. Whereas setting it to a string representation of the `SpannableStringBuilder` doesn't apply formatting at all. So you should replace the line:

   ```
   text = ssb;
   ```

   with:

   ```
   textView.setText(sbb);
   ```

   and delete the latter:

   ```
   textView.setText(text);
   ```

The final code is as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_format_test);
    format();
    // Your custom code was here, deleted for readability
}

public void format() {
    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.test);

    CharSequence text = null;

    if (textView != null) {
        text = textView.getText();
    }

    String token = "^^";

    if (text != null) {
        int length = token.length();
        int start = text.toString().indexOf(token) + length;
        int end = text.toString().indexOf(token, start + length);

        if (start > -1 && end > -1) {
            SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);
            ssb.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(0xff000000), start, end, 0);
            ssb.delete(end, end + length);
            ssb.delete(start - length, start);

            textView.setText(ssb);
            System.out.println("format");
        }

        System.out.println("works");
    }

    System.out.println("running");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this code, but I have one big problem with it. That is if I try to use more than 1 of the ^^ tokens in a text it will only format it once. Where do I change it to change it twice?

Comment: what do you mean by "use more than 1 of ^^ tokens"? do you mean like `aa^^bb^^cc^^dd^^ee` or having multiple tokens like: one is `^^` another `**`, etc.? this code is currently not ready for multiple occurrences of `^^xx^^` since it's based on your version which attempted to format only one occurrence.

Comment: I would like to be able to use both of those. So more of the same and different ones.

Comment: so just make the `token` a parameter and add a loop - basically it should replace the `if (text != null) {` condition. inside replace consecutive pairs of `token`. then `break;` from the loop when `start < 0 || end < 0`. change the `text` to be a valid `Spannable`.

Comment: Nvm. Fixed all my problems. Thanks for the help.